# Fusion charts with custom context menu

Tags: fusioncharts, custom-contextmenu

I am using Fusion charts and want to add a few custom menu on the right click(apart from the one displayed).
In the fusion charts blog, they say we cannot add our own custom menu but we can change only **About** menu.
Is there any work around so that i can add at least one menu of my own, clicking on which will call a javascript function

I am using flash to render fusion chart.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a new menu item - but you can replace the text and click action of existing one, as explained at http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/AttDesc/CustomAboutMenu.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I know we can change the About context menu, but i don't need to change. I need to add a new context menu.Is there any work around for this??

Comment: The change in about menu allows you to at least add one single custom menu item. Adding more than that is not supported. :( By the way, if you are using JavaScript variant of FusionCharts, context-menu is not there at all (to make it behave uniformly on touch and on-touch devices.)